# How to determine that PDImageXObject contain specific image

Tags: java, spring-boot, pdfbox

**I have 5 images**

sun.png

moon.png

sea.png

earth.png

sky.png

**I put these images into pdf via pdf box and**
**I am able to identify the instance of PDImageXObject**

```
PDXObject pdxObject = getResources().getXObject(objectName);
if (pdxObject instanceof PDImageXObject) {
 //I want earth.png 
 PDImageXObject image = (PDImageXObject)xobject;
 BufferedImage bImage = image.getImage();
 String fileName='earth.png'; // How can I get same file name as it was at the time of placing on pdf
 ImageIO.write(bImage,"PNG",new File(fileName));
 System.out.println("earth saved.");

}
```

But how can I determine that this PDImageXObject is earth.png one? ; and

How can I get same file name as it was at the time of placing on pdf

Comment: File names are usually not stored on the PDF.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

There is no clear way to decide on number of images in a PDF without considering what you mean by images.

It is not as simple as counting visible content, nor use an extraction listing. Here are 5 images on the page, but the page is considered as only having one image, even though I can drag and scale the smaller copies. However, none have names that say Sun Moon Earth and Sea. They did as sun, moon, earth & sea.png but in a PDF they are given different names and ALL 5 are placed in the file as `/Im0` but allocated different object numbers and different IDentity descriptions, It does not matter how many places they are linked to, nor total number of copies, they will simply be known by placements, so often the writer will keep it brief as /Im0 /Im1 /Im2 etc. Thus I was slightly surprised to see here there is only /Im0. But I suppose its how you count as a "page canvas media" when overlaying.
Each image has its own "fixed page" but we don't count images as pages here they are called a "form".

[image]

```
<</BBox[0 0 430 430]/Type/XObject/Length 39/Resources<</XObject<</Im0 16 0 R>>>>/Subtype/Form>>
stream
q
430 0 0 430 0 0 cm
/Im0 Do
Q
q
Q
q
Q

endstream
endobj

13 0 obj
<</BBox[0 0 430 430]/Type/XObject/Length 39/Resources<</XObject<</Im0 17 0 R>>>>/Subtype/Form>>
stream
q
430 0 0 430 0 0 cm
/Im0 Do
Q
q
Q
q
Q

endstream
endobj

14 0 obj
<</BBox[0 0 430 430]/Type/XObject/Length 39/Resources<</XObject<</Im0 18 0 R>>>>/Subtype/Form>>
stream
q
430 0 0 430 0 0 cm
/Im0 Do
```

So Mutool (base for pyMuPDF) agrees in "info" query
`Images (1):  1  (4 0 R):  [ ASCIIHex ] 1720x860 8bpc DevRGB (10 0 R)`
Ok that expected lets extract

```
extracting image-0010.png
extracting image-0015.png
extracting image-0016.png
extracting image-0017.png
extracting image-0018.png
extracting image-0019.png
extracting image-0020.png
extracting image-0021.png
extracting image-0022.png
```

So that's expected too there is one image and 8 other different images each a sub layer(s) of the 4 visible.

earth is 16 and 20
moon  is 17 and 21
sea   is 18 and 22
sun   is 15 and 19

However those 8 different pngs are nothing like the source pngs since they are simply shadows of the inputs.

The inter relationship is seen better in

```
pdfimages -list clipboard4.pdf
page   num  type   width height color comp bpc  enc interp  object ID x-ppi y-ppi size ratio
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1     0 image    1720   860  rgb     3   8  image  no        10  0    96    96 8803K 203%
   1     1 image     430   430  rgb     3   8  image  no        15  0   249   249 1100K 203%
   1     2 smask     430   430  gray    1   8  image  no        15  0   249   249  367K 203%
   1     3 image     430   430  rgb     3   8  image  no        16  0   160   160 1100K 203%
   1     4 smask     430   430  gray    1   8  image  no        16  0   160   160  367K 203%
   1     5 image     430   430  rgb     3   8  image  no        17  0   288   288 1100K 203%
   1     6 smask     430   430  gray    1   8  image  no        17  0   288   288  367K 203%
   1     7 image     430   430  rgb     3   8  image  no        18  0   198   198 1100K 203%
   1     8 smask     430   430  gray    1   8  image  no        18  0   198   198  367K 203%
```